# Query for concatenating time fields using - operator in between

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have two different columns in database `Start Time` And `End Time` and in Grid View I have like this `09:00:00-09:30:00` in single column.How should I write Sql Query to search and concatenate two time fields from  in database  and there is - operator in between time in Grid View.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @a table ([Start Time] time,[End Time] Time)

Insert into @a Values ('9:00','18:00')

Select Cast([Start Time] as Varchar(8))+'-'+Cast([End Time] as Varchar(8))
from @a
```

If your columns are Datetime it would be

```
declare @a table ([Start Time] Datetime,[End Time] DateTime)

Insert into @a Values ('9:00','18:00')

Select Convert(Varchar(8),[Start Time],114)+'-'+Convert(Varchar(8),[End Time],114)
from @a
```